# Copy variable between SPSS Datasets using Syntax

Tags: spss

EDITED based on feedback...

Is there a way to copy a variable form one open dataset to another in SPSS? What I have tried is to create a scratch variable that captures the value of the variable, and use that scratch variable in a Compute command into the next dataset:

```
DATASET ACTIVATE DataSet1.
COMPUTE #IDSratch = ID.
Dataset Activate DataSet2.
Compute ID = #IDScratch.
```

This fails because activating Dataset2 causes the scratch variable to be dropped from memory.

Match Files and/or STAR JOIN syntax will work for most scenarios but in my case because Dataset1 has many more records than Dataset2 AND there are no matching keys in both datasets, this yields extra records.

My original question was "Is there a simple, direct way of copying a variable between datasets?" and the answer still appears to be that merging the files via syntax is the best/only method if using syntax.

Comment: When you create your scratch variable, you create *it in the active dataset* - it doesn't exist in any other dataset.   
The only way to attach the data from one dataset to the other like you want is by matching the files - no cases will be added if you do it right... Please add a description of the datasets (+ a bit of sample data will help too) so we can understand the problem and suggest a suitable solution.

Comment: not clear from your edit if you are still seeking an answer? if so, see my comment above - we can probably assist with a syntax solution but only if you provide a description of the data structure + an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since SPSS version 21.0, the `STAR JOIN` command [(see documentation here)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_24.0.0/spss/base/syn_star_join.html) allows you to use SQL syntax to join datasets. So basically, you could get only the variables you want from each dataset.

Assume your first dataset is called data_1 and has `id` and `var_1a`. Your second data is called data_2, has the same `id` and `var_2a`; and you just want to pull `var_2a` to the first dataset. If both datasets are open, you can run:

```
dataset activate data_1.
STAR JOIN
  /SELECT t0.var_1a, t1.var_2a
  /FROM * AS t0
  /JOIN 'data_2' AS t1
    ON t0.id=t1.id
  /OUTFILE FILE=*.
```

The link I provided above has plenty of examples on how to join variables of files that are saved in your computer.

Comment: +1 on the star join, though I suspect from reading the OP that there is a problem that the table from which we want to get data is not a keyed table - which is what would produce the "extra records" problem. If so, this would require an additional step like aggregation.

Comment: Ow, ok. I re-read it and now I got what you said. It seems that you are right

Comment: Thanks to you both. I was using OMS to generate multiple datasets from a single dataset which had unique keys needed to automatically export the OMS-datasets into a SQL database. It ended up being easier to do this matching outside of SPSS. Cheers